# how to get dataUsage of an app in android version 4.3 (jellybean) TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid) does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-version

Morning

Does anyone know a method of getting the data usage of an app based on its ID in version 4.3 I tried using`TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid)` but that only returns 0 and after some research I found that this is because of version 4.3 , what is the work around to this

Comment: This `TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid)` available only `>= 5.0`

Comment: @MD you are right so in 4.3 how would I go about getting that

Comment: Don't know but you can check [NetworkInfoRepo](https://github.com/manishpatelgt/NetworkInfoRepo). my code i have developed such app